# Is there a time lag in the YouTube Data API 3 rate endpoint?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an application that displays a YouTube video and has a rate button to allow a user to like or unlike the video. On the click event 3 functions are called chained together through the `success` function of the ajax. The flow is this: `ytvRate()` -> `getRating()` -> `showRating()`

When I log the actions and results the response from `getRating()` does not have the value that I sent in `ytvRate()`. If I wait a while and refresh the page, the result of `getRating()` comes back correct. I call `getRating()` inside the success function of the ajax in `ytvRate()`. Doesn't that mean the function should not be called until a success response is received?

Here is an example of my logs:

```
rating sent: like
call get rating
this is my rating: none
call show rating
```

As you can see, the rating returned from the API is not correct - it should be the rating I just sent. Upon refresh the same call does return the correct rating... so, is there a delay or something to the data api updating the correct information? How can I get the correct rating on the same button click that sends the request?

Here are the functions (`showRating` does not seem relevant to the problem. It works fine as long as it gets the correct rating - which it is not.)

```
function ytvRate(id, rating, event){
    event.preventDefault()

    var apiKey = 'This is a valid key';
    var client_id = 'This is a valid client id';
    var redirect_uri = 'This is a redirect uri';
    var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube';
    var rateUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id='+id+'&key='+apiKey+'&rating='+rating;

    if(getHash().access_token){
        var token = getHash().access_token;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: rateUrl,
            beforeSend: function (request){
                request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('rating sent: '+rating); 
                getRating(id);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
         });

    } else{
        window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id='+client_id+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&scope='+scope+'&response_type=token&prompt=consent&include_granted_scopes=false';
    }
    return false;
}

function getRating(id){
    var getRatingUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating?id='+id;
    console.log('call get rating');
    if(getHash().access_token){
        var token = getHash().access_token;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: getRatingUrl,
            beforeSend: function (request){
                request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success: function(data){
                var rating = data.items[0].rating;
                console.log("this is my rating: " + rating);
                showRating(rating, id);
            }
         });
    }
}

function showRating(response, id){
    console.log('call show rating');
    numLikes(id);
    if(response == 'like'){
        document.getElementById("notliked").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("liked").className = "";
        document.getElementById("like-btn").style.color = "#87CEFA";
        document.getElementById("like-btn").setAttribute("onclick", "ytvRate('"+id+"', 'none', event)");
    } else{
        document.getElementById("notliked").className = "";
        document.getElementById("liked").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("like-btn").style.color = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("like-btn").setAttribute("onclick", "ytvRate('"+id+"', 'like', event)");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Interestingly, if I call the `youtube/v3/videos` resource in a new method instead of `youtube/v3/videos/getRating` and access the `statistics.likeCount`, the number is instantly updated. Why can I not receive the user rating with the same efficiency?

Comment: Have you tried disabling caching on the `getRating` request? `$.ajax({ cache: false, ...`. The response may be cached if you previously requested it. Otherwise, it's possible that they don't immediately update the rating in order to combat spam voting.

Comment: @MikeC Nice suggestion... I just tried it and the result is the same. No luck.

Comment: Can you send a POST request instead of GET? POST requests shouldn't be cached. Another option is to append an unique random cache invalidation string to the request url like &nocache=RANDOMSTRING. If all of that fails it might be googleapis fault.

Comment: @Ciunkos Thank you for your suggestions. I tried both, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments I suggest you to take a different approach. When `ytvRate` success you don't need to fetch `getRating` as you already know what is the rating set by the user.

The `rate` method is like a setter in regular programming language - if it successed (didn't throw an exception or returned an error) you can assume the current value is the one you set without fetching it again. This might be wrong assumption in multithreaded/distributed enviroments but might be ok in your case.

```
function ytvRate(id, rating, event){
    ...
    success: function(data){
        console.log('rating sent: '+rating); 
        showRating(rating, id);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did try this... however, the rate status gets in a bad state when not explicitly checking. For example, if I switch between the youtube page and my page it can show different ratings for my user. As I have a single thumbs icon that will show either liked(blue) or unrated(white), this results in my app displaying the wrong rate request. (It will show as liked - click will send unlike request, when on youtube I do not have the video liked.)

Comment: I'm tending to think googleapis must have some built in latency to prevent some unwanted behavior, but I don't know what this would be... In the native youtube site the rating behavior is immediate.

Comment: I agree with you that there may be a delay for third-party apps. 
If you fetch `getRating` initialy in order to display buttons there is another solution using the `etag` value returned from `getRating`. You can store this value, then after rating submission and getRating you read the `etag` field.  If it is the same it means the rating is not yet updated. You can then delay another refetch until etag changes.

Comment: I have just checked how YouTube website behaves under same conditions and... it is the same as you described! The "immediate" effect is just an optimistic one and also suffers from the delay when clicked on multiple tabs/sessions.

Comment: That's interesting, so the `etag` value only changes when an update is recorded? I think your solution of show-rating-on-faith is probably the best. Plus, with the fast update of the like count it appears ok from the user perspective. With the etag what would I do, set an interval loop to keep checking `getRating` until the etag changes?